# Copy command is not working using Wix Custom Action

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.6, wix3.7

I have the following `CustomAction`:

```
<CustomAction Id="CopyToSystem32" ExeCommand="copy /y 64bits.txt C:\Windows\System32" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Impersonate="no" Execute="deferred" Return="asyncWait" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="CopyToSystem32" After="InstallFiles" >VersionNT64</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

So when it detects a 64 bits OS, it will copy a file to System32 folder. If I execute it with a .bat file, it works fine. But I would prefer it to be a batch command.

The log says the following:

```
MSI (s) (74:AC) [10:08:33:473]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=CopyToSystem32,,)
Action 10:08:33: CopyToSystem32. 
MSI (s) (74:AC) [10:08:33:473]: Executing op:         CustomActionSchedule(Action=CopyToSystem32,ActionType=3234,Source=C:\Program Files    (x86)\SetupProject\,Target=copy /y 64bits.txt C:\Windows\System32,)
MSI (s) (74:AC) [10:08:33:474]: Executing op:     ActionStart(Name=RegisterProduct,Description=Registering product,Template=[1])
Action 10:08:33: RegisterProduct. Registering product
MSI (s) (74:AC) [10:08:33:474]: Executing op: ChangeMedia(,MediaPrompt=Please insert the disk:     ,MediaCabinet=1\cab1.cab,BytesPerTick=0,CopierType=1,,,SignatureRequired=0,,,IsFirstPhysicalMedia=1)
MSI (s) (74:AC) [10:08:33:474]: Executing op:     DatabaseCopy(DatabasePath=C:\Windows\Installer\32ea43.msi,ProductCode={0C013216-61FB-4283-AF0A-    6CB264019F5B},,,)
MSI (s) (74:AC) [10:08:33:474]: Note: 1: 1402 2:     UNKNOWN\Products\612310C0BF163824FAA0C62B4610F9B5\InstallProperties 3: 2 
1: CopyToSystem32 2: 1631
```

Any idea on why my `ExeCommand` is not copying my file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK `copy` is part of the command shell interpreter and not a command on its own. E..g You can check this if you e.g. do a `dir copy.* /s` in the `Windows`-folder.  There is no file that independently implements `copy`.
What you can do: prepend the invocation of the command interpreter, e.g.:

```
cmd /c copy /y 64bits.txt C:\Windows\System32
```

The `/c`-parameter tells the interpreter to close after the execution (you could also use the `[%COMSPEC]`-environment variable instead of `cmd`). You could also use the `CAQuietExecute` custom action to prevent the cmd popup, as described [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html).
Maybe you could also just use the [`CopyFile`-element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/copyfile.html) for your task? This way you don't have to deal with the shell window etc.

Comment: Wow, perfect! Just that! I will also take a look to the CAQuiteExecute you mention. Thanks again! A++++

Comment: I forgot the other possibilities using either `xcopy.exe` or `robocopy.exe` instead of `cmd /c copy`. Both are available in the `System32`-folder. However, if possible, the simplest and most elegant way would be to use the mechanisms that Windows Installer / WiX provides, i.e. using the `CopyFile`-element, if possible.